# How to find which quick release to buy

Tags: mountain-bike, quick-release, hardtail

I own a **Serious Rockville Hardtail MTB 27.5'** bike from 2019. Recently the quick release from the rear wheel got stolen.

As the axle is still in place, I was thinking to buy a quick release online and trying fixing myself. But when browsing online I could see different types of QRs in the market, in terms of length which actually make sense.

I was wondering whether we could find out which skewer to buy based on the bike specifications.

These are the specifications I could find from the manufactures website.

| Component | Details |
| --- | --- |
| Rims | Meghna Disc Specific 512-035 aluminum double wall 27.5 inches |
| Front tire | Meghna MR-2620 2.1 inches |
| Rear tire | Meghna MR-2620 2.1 inches |
| Hub (front) | KT KT-MD7F |
| Hub (rear) | KT KT-TD4R |
| Tire size (inch) | 27.5 ″ |
| Impeller size | 27.5 ″ |

Updated: You can find the bike model [here](https://marktplatz.bike/Serious-Rockville%2027%2C5%22%20Disc%20%7C%2042%20cm%20%7C%20grey%20%7C%20Modelljahr%202019)
They dont sell the same bikes anymore. I think they updated the model in 2020, here is the [new one](https://marktplatz.bike/Serious-Rockville%2027%2C5%22%20Disc%20%7C%2042%20cm%20%7C%20black%2Fblack%20%7C%20Modelljahr%202020). But I assume the measurements might be the same, especially for the QRs.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn’t find the manufacturer website, so I couldn’t confirm if the bike had quick releases or thru axles. I know you said quick release, but thru axles are very common on disc brake bikes these days.

If you do have a QR, you would need to look for a 135mm rear QR. That’s the standard length for MTB rear hubs. Road bikes used 130mm, but you could use an MTB QR on a road bike. If a manufacturer doesn’t list a length for the rear QR, you can often assume it’s 135mm. To my knowledge, Salsa Cycles, a common aftermarket QR, does this, and this seems to be the general practice on online retailers. I updated the [terminology index page](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/404/38270) on QRs to include this information. You could avoid getting any QRs that are associated with a road-only brand, e.g. Shimano Ultegra or Dura Ace QRs.

The [terminology index entry for thru axles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/41723/38270) has a photo of a thru axle with a quick release beside it. If you have a thru axle, replacement will be more annoying because there are many different lengths. The entry has a guide to replacing those.

Comment: Thank you very much @Weiwen. I updated the question with the link to the bike model. From the index entry, I think mine is not thru-axle.

Comment: @AnuBhuvanendranNair I don’t read German, but I think I see quick release nuts on the drive side of the bike. Thru axles would be flush with the dropout.

Comment: A hub with 135mm over-locknut distance evidently needs longer than a 135mm skewer.

Comment: @MaplePanda true. For simplicity, I omitted that part. The fact is almost all retailers will list skewers as 135mm, if they list a length. Interestingly enough, Trek seems to list its skewers in actual length. https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/equipment/cycling-components/bike-wheels/bike-skewers/bontrager-elite-internal-cam-skewer/p/14309/?colorCode=black

Comment: I reckon QR from the pic of the 2020 model as well.  I'd be surprised if a >135mm rear hub was QR, so 135mm should be good.  I read just enough German to reckon the specs don't give that much detail even if I look at "Nabe (hinten)" (rear hub) on the 2020 model and search the part number, it seems to be a discontinued  OEM part, and the [new model](https://www.ktgroup.net/pro.php?m=d&pid=30&cid=71&f=65) has both QR and TA versions.

Comment: Note (@MaplePanda) that the nominal dimension of  a mechanical part may not be any physical dimension on the part but a mating dimension or a reference dimension.  This is particularly true on  threads for pipes, but even common metric screws are always narrower than the nominal size (the thread is specified to be flat-topped; if it wasn't, the diameter would match the nominal size)

Comment: @ChrisH Salsa lists fat bike QR skewers on their website, and they were really wide. That’s the exception, though.

Comment: @WeiwenNg It’s been a while since I last bought a QR skewer, but I remember they were sold according to external dropout spacing. Aluminum frames with thicker dropouts would need longer QRs than thin steel dropouts. I suppose it varies greatly.

Comment: @ChrisH See my comment to Weiwen. Side note: there’s the 141mm “QR Boost” standard used by some budget hardtails, and there might be fat bike stuff too.

Comment: @MaplePanda With QR on my steel and aluminium bikes I can see that.  However they seem to be titled by nominal size ("front"/"rear"/"boost") rather than actual length, with the actual length in the specs if you're lucky.  This all reminds me - I need a new skewer for my hardtail: external cam+ disc brakes mean I need to check frequently or risk losing the wheel landing even my little jumps

Comment: @ChrisH Looks to vary heavily by brand I guess. The Shimano ones I'm familiar with have packaging like the following with many length options: https://www.ebay.com/p/14006749252

Comment: Interestingly @MaplePanda while there are tickboxes for the true length, they haven't actually been ticked